# $(x^TAx)(x^TA^{-1}x)\leq \max_{1\leq i \leq n} \left( c\lambda_i +\frac{1}{c\lambda_i} \right)$ for any $c >0$ if $A$ is s.p.d.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, numerical-linear-algebra, numerical-optimization, symmetric-matrices

Suppose that $A$ is an $n \times n$ symmetric positive definite matrix. Assume that its eigenvalues are $\lambda_1 \leq \ldots \leq \lambda_n$. I would like to show that

$$(x^TAx)(x^TA^{-1}x)\leq \max_{1\leq i \leq n} \left(c\lambda_i +\frac{1}{c\lambda_i}    \right)$$

for any $c >0$.

This inequality seems quite strong since it is true for any $c>0$. If there is an error, please let me know.

Since $A$ is symmetric, by the Real Spectral Theorem, I know that there exists a basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$ consisting of orthonormal eigenvectors $e_1, \ldots, e_n$ of $A$. Suppose that $\lambda_1 \leq \ldots \leq \lambda_n$ are the corresponding eigenvalues of $e_1, \ldots, e_n$, respectively.

I know that
$$(x^TAx)(x^TA^{-1}x)= \left( \sum_{i=1}^n (e_i^Tx)^2\lambda_i  \right)  \left( \sum_{i=1}^n (e_i^Tx)^2\frac{1}{\lambda_i}  \right).$$

Note that $\lambda_i>0$ for each $1 \leq i \leq n$ since $A$ is positive definite.

This is where I get stuck. I have been told that I can use the Cauchy Schwarz Inequality and the arithmetic geometric mean inequality to obtain the result, but I keep reaching a dead end.

Any help is extremely appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Do you have conditions on $x$?

Comment: What you write there under "I know that" is false.

Comment: @amsmath Sorry, I think I fixed it.

Comment: @angryavian Maybe we can assume that $x$ is normalized? I am not sure.

Comment: You should leave away the $e_i$ in the end of each sum

Comment: @amsmath Ahh, yes, these are scalars...stupid mistakes. Thank you

Comment: Look [here](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/jres/64B/jresv64Bn1p33_A1b.pdf). I do not think you can do better than that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For ease of notation I will handle the case where $A=\text{diag}(\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n)$. The argument (once completed...) can easily be modified to the general case by a change of basis.

\begin{align}
x^\top A x x^\top A^{-1} x
&= x^\top (cA) x x^\top (cA)^{-1} x
\\
&= \left(\sum_i c\lambda_i x_i^2\right)\left(\sum_i \frac{1}{c\lambda_i} x_i^2\right)
\\
&\le \frac{1}{4} \left(\sum_i \left(c\lambda_i + \frac{1}{c\lambda_i}\right) x_i^2\right)^2 & \text{AM-GM}
\\
&\le \frac{1}{4} \left(\sum_i x_i^2\right)^2 \max_i \left(c\lambda_i + \frac{1}{c\lambda_i}\right)^2
\\
&= \frac{1}{4} \max_i \left(c\lambda_i + \frac{1}{c\lambda_i}\right)^2 & \text{if $\|x\|_2 \le 1$}
\end{align}

My final answer looks slightly different than yours, but perhaps I have made some errors...

---

Subsequent details, in response to comments below. (Details sketched out by A.Γ., thanks!)

Because $f(z) := z + \frac{1}{z}$ is a convex function, we have
$$g(c) := \max_i \left(c \lambda_i + \frac{1}{c \lambda_i}\right) = \max_i f(c\lambda_i) = \max\{f(c\lambda_1), f(c \lambda_n)\}.$$

To get the best upper bound, we want to minimize $g$ with respect to $c$. 
As claimed below, the minimizer, $c_*$, is the solution to $f(c \lambda_1) = f(c\lambda_n)$.
Then we obtain $c_*=(\lambda_1 \lambda_n)^{-1/2}$ and the final value is $\sqrt{\lambda_1/\lambda_n} + \sqrt{\lambda_n/\lambda_1}$ which yields the [Kantorovich inequality](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/jres/64B/jresv64Bn1p33_A1b.pdf).

To see why solving $f(c \lambda_1) = f(c\lambda_n)$ yields the minimizer, you can note that both $c \mapsto f(c\lambda_1)$ and $c \mapsto f(c\lambda_n)$ are convex functions that have the same minimum value $2$ at minimizers $c=1/\lambda_1$ and $c=1/\lambda_n$ respectively. You can draw some pictures to get the intuition for why solving $f(c \lambda_1) = f(c\lambda_n)$ yields the minimizer and then make this rigorous.

Comment: You have not made any mistake. Also, yours it better than OP's in the case of the identity. Actually, I wonder whether OP's inequality is valid.

Comment: You have (almost) arrived to [Kantorovich inequality](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/jres/64B/jresv64Bn1p33_A1b.pdf).

Comment: @amsmath I do not thing it is valid as OP stated. A counterexample for $A=\text{diag}\,(m,1/m)$, $x_1^2=x_2^2=1/2$ and $c=1$ seems to work as $m\to 0^+$ since the LHS is quadratic and the RHS is linear in $m+1/m$.

Comment: @angryavian The original inequality was a hint given to me by a professor to prove the Kantorovich inequality. I had a strong feeling that his hint is incorrect. If I assume your inequality, then I can prove the Kantorovich inequality with no problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Sarah How do you derive the Kantorovic inequality from angryavian's inequality?

Comment: @amsmath You get Kantorovich if you minimize the RHS on $c>0$. The minimum is easily when $f(c\lambda_{\min})=f(c\lambda_{\max})$ where $f(x)=x+1/x$.

Comment: @A.Γ. Ok, thanks. But how do I minimize the maximum of several functions by hand?

Comment: @amsmath The function $f$ is convex, so maximum is attained at one of the end points, which are $\lambda_{\min}$ and $\lambda_{\max}$. To make this maximum to be as small as possible, one has to choose $c$ that scales all lambda to get the equality above. To put it formally, if $f(c\lambda_{\min})\ne f(c\lambda_{\max})$ then one can change $c$ a bit to get a smaller max.

Comment: @amsmath Yes, precisely!

Comment: @A.Γ. I don't get that. Why should we maximize $f$? We have $g(c) = \max_i f(c\lambda_i)$ and we want to minimize $g$, right? Sure, $f$ is convex, and so is $g$. I would be thankful for a little more explanation.

Comment: @amsmath The only maximization that A.Γ. is doing is the one you have written yourself: $\max_i f(c \lambda_i)$. Everything else in A.Γ.'s explanation is to minimize $g(c)$.

Comment: @amsmath We should maximize $f$ to get $g(c)$. Because $f$ is convex we have $g(c)=\max\{f(c\lambda_{\min}),f(c\lambda_{\max})\}$.

Comment: Thanks, guys. Got it now. And there is only exactly one $c$ such that $f(c\lambda_\min) = f(c\lambda_\max)$.